# haproxy redirect custom http traffic to a custom https port

Tags: ssl, https, haproxy, redirection

I wish to redirect my custom http port traffic to custom https port based on the port I receive traffic on

I have multiple bind statements :

```
 bind 1.2.3.4:7777
 bind 1.2.3.4:8888
 bind 1.2.3.4:9999 ssl crt /etc/haporxy/somecert.crt
```

What I've tried :

```
acl is7777 dst_port 7777
http-request redirect code 301 https://%[req.hdr(Host)]:9999%[capture.req.uri] if is7777
```

However when I look at the logs in Chrome's dev tools I always see that the value of req.hdr(Host) is preserving the value of the old port so I get redirected to

```
 https://1.2.3.4:7777/:9999/.
```

How do i get just the domain name and redirect it to the desired destination port of 9999

Also, something like this :

```
http-request replace-value Host (.*):7777 \1:9999
```

Breaks the application flow since there are multiple redirects later. I need to go from 7777(http) to 9999(https) .
haproxy version: 1.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either remove port from `redirect` or `replace-value`

```
http-request replace-value Host (.*):7777 \1
http-request redirect location https://%[req.hdr(Host)]:9999%[capture.req.uri] if is7777
```

OR

```
http-request replace-value Host (.*):7777 \1:9999
http-request redirect location https://%[req.hdr(Host)]%[capture.req.uri] if is7777
```

Comment: thanks so much ! works as expected. to add to your solution i added a "if is7777" in the replace-value line.

Comment: what does `capture.req.uri` do ?